# Matplotlib graph's x-axis labels are incorrectly placed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Please consider the weekly series:

```
series
Out[71]: 
index
2019-02-17    -804.500
2019-02-24    -478.500
2019-03-03   -2168.070
2019-03-10    2231.800
2019-03-17    -340.500
Freq: W-SUN, Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Bar plot,

```
plt.bar(height = series, x = series.index)
```

leads to:
[image]

**Issue:**

As you can see, the x-axis dates are not the dates in the series' index, and thus they do not appear vertically-aligned with the bars. How can I have matplotlib show series' index as x-axis labels?

Comment: This may help https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

Comment: Matplotlib's `bar` plot is created on a continuous scale. It seems you want a categorical graph instead. Using matplotlib this would be achieved by plotting strings instead of dates. Or, using pandas `df.plot.bar` function this would be automatically the case.